# Assessing free disk space in Windows machines by Powershell and Ansible 2.4

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I am trying to write an Ansible task which execute a Powershell command to retrieve disk free space of the C drive on a Windows 7 Remote machine and then do a simple output to printscreen. I am failing in extracting the necessary information.

I tried to go through the element of rawcsize replacing rawcsize.stdout[0] with rawcsize.stdout[1] or rawcsize.stdout[2]

The playbook is composed in the following way:

```
  - name: Retrieve Disk Usage
    win_shell: 'Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Free'
    register: rawcsize

#  # Convert disk size in Gigabytes
  - name: Convert system disk into various formats and export
    vars:
      disk_out_free: '{{ rawcsize.stdout[0] }}'
      disk_int: '{{ rawcsize.stdout | int }}'
      disk_gb: '{{ disk_int | int}}'
    debug:
      msg: 'rawcsize.stdout: {{(rawcsize.stdout)}} disk_out_free: {{(disk_out_free)}}  disk_int: {{(disk_int)}} disk_gb: {{(disk_gb)}}'
```

## The output is the following:

ok: [192.168.122.3] => {}

MSG:

rawcsize.stdout:
       Free
       ----
35229712384

disk_int: 0 disk_gb: 0

So the variable "disk_out_free" is not visible. Why is this happening? And how can I extract only the necessary information from the Powershell output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet you can output json from PowerShell and then use the `from_json` Jinja2 filter to read it in.

```
- name: get disk free space
  win_shell: Get-PsDrive c | ConvertTo-Json
  register: output

- name: extract free space
  set_fact:
    free_json: "{{ output.stdout|from_json}}"

- name:
  debug:
    var: free_json.Free
```

**Produces:**

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host.example.com]

TASK [get disk free space] **************************************************************************************
changed: [host.example.com]

TASK [extract free space] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host.example.com]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host.example.com] => {
    "free_json.Free": "18444869632"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
host.example.com : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```